# Is there any language where each character is pronounced differently depending on the word it's in?

Tags: orthography, list-of-languages

Languages like Japanese have different pronunciations for each character (in the kanji system in this case) , a kanji character can have up to 20 different pronunciations depending on the the word it is in. Is there or was there any language where each character is pronounced differently depending on the word it's in?

Comment: Do you something like English where there is a poor mapping of characters to pronunciation, mostly rule based but lots of exceptions ? Does _every_ character have to have multiple pronunciations? 'k' is always 'k'. but 'c' can be like k' or 's' or part of 'ch'. 'p' can be the usual or part of 'ph' or silent (and most others have at least one other pronunciation). I feel like each of the vowels cover many vowel sounds.

Comment: In English you can guess more or less the pronunciation for each word you dont know. I'm talking about a language where you are completely blank about how to pronounce the characters before learning because they are radically different most of the times.

Comment: Isn't Kanji the same, meaning you don't know which of a handful of pronunciations before learning, but there are actual clues sometimes in some characters (ell, that is the case for those characters in Chinese, I don't know for Japanese).

Comment: But to your point, spelling systems while not always designed codes ab initio, attempt to be so, and such a coding scheme where _every_ character_ has multiple mappings not determinable by context would have very poor learnability and very poor utility.

Comment: Bear in mind that not all language "spelling" schemes are phonetic.

Comment: In Kanjis in japanese you could have up to 20 pronunciations of a kanji character depending on the word it is in. But I'm wondering if something more extreme exists, where the characters just give a sense of partial meaning to the word, but the word itself determines the pronunciation, meaning the character could have practically any pronunciation depending on the word it is in

Comment: @Mitch "k" can be silent: _knight_.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry. May be I wrote the question wrongly. Everybody seems to be talking about nuances in the sound of a character. When what I was talking it's completely different sounds. For example, the kanji for person 人has the readings jin, nin, hito. I thought the word "pronunciation" would apply to that but since everybody is talking about nuances it seems it doesnt?

Comment: @Pablo What is your motivation for this question? Simply curiosity? Or a good counter example for theories? Or to rank spelling systems by difficulty? This will help in giving better answers to your liking.

Comment: May be I should edit the question and change the word pronunciation for reading? The motivation is fan fiction writing, feasibility

Comment: @Pablo I think part of the problem is that you're asking this question from the perspective that "In English you can guess more or less the pronunciation for each word you don't know", but in my experience this is actually not at all true, certainly *not significantly more true* than it is that you can generally guess what every kanji reads like from context. That is to say, I think a lot of people are trying to say that your intuition is trained by your familiarity with English to think about these things as more distinctly different than they really are.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Why isn't it on hold? I doubt OP's hypothesis is true for all Kanji. And even for the signs with many readings, they often have a primary sense and reading, where the others have to be gleamed from context. Switching context is not unlike code switching, which is not unlike switching language. Hence, it shouldn't be surprising that characters like "+" may have different readings even in English alone (cross, plus, and). It's also pretty much out of the question whether logographic writing was invented and formalized independently multiple times.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_script

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't Japanese an answer to this question? Didn't you just answer your own question? What is the question here? I think some clarification is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unlikely that in some language's writing system, each and every character is pronounced differently depending on the word it's in. For that to be true, it would mean that every character has at least two pronunciations. The implication of "what word it is in" is that what determines the pronunciation is the word, and not the general context (for instance, the Devanagari letter त is pronounced differently when it is combined with the letter ि). Kanji may have multiple readings, for example 明 can be *myō* or *mei*. Chinese also has multiple readings for a character. But not all characters are like that.

A candidate for such writing is the Phoenician alphabet, which (originally) only marked consonants, though of course the language did have vowels. So "" could represent [la, li, lu, l] and you would just have to know what the word is. But this is quite different from the situation with readings for Chinese characters. Still, it might be the kind of thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

There is, as a matter of fact!

Cuneiform ("wedge-shaped") was a writing system originally developed for the Sumerian language, then adapted for Akkadian, Hittite, and many other languages. But the adaptation process was not particularly consistent. Take this Sumerian glyph for example:

[image: DIŊIR glyph]

It originally meant the words *an*, "heaven", or *An*, "An, the god of the sky". But through synecdoche it could also mean *diŋir*, "deity". And when cuneiform started being used for sounds instead of words, it also meant the syllable `/an/`.

Then the Akkadians started using the writing system. In Akkadian, this sign was used for the words *il* ("god"), or *šamû* ("heaven"), taken straightforwardly from the Sumerian meanings. *But*, it could still be used for the syllable `/an/` from Sumerian, *and* now for the syllable `/il/` from Akkadian!

In fact, some signs, including this one ("DIŊIR", written in capitals to indicate the sign as opposed to any particular interpretation) could also be used as *determiners*, and not pronounced at all! When written before a name, this sign indicates that it's the name of a deity. This is mostly used for clarifying the huge mess of homophones created by this system.

Comment: Are you claiming that all Sumerian hieroglyph characters have multiple pronunciations, or that some/most do?

Comment: @user6726 In Akkadian and Hittite, all the ones I've seen have multiple readings: at a minimum, they can be read as either native words/sounds, or Sumerian words/sounds.

Comment: @user6726: Well, there are some cuneiform signs (not hieroglyphs; that word has a reasonably well defined meaning, and cuneiform doesn't fit it) which only have one _known_ reading, even considering all the languages cuneiform was used to write. For example, some particularly elaborate combination signs like [dalhamun₄](https://twitter.com/cooleiform/status/942303349499678721) are AFAIK only attested from a single source (in this case, a list of divine epithets) that gives them a single reading. Some archaic signs that fell out of use or merged with other signs early on might also qualify.

Comment: ... Then again, especially in the earliest sources there are also quite a few signs that we simply know _no_ pronunciation for, even if we might sometimes be able to guess from context (or from the signs they're composed of, in case of combination signs) what they probably mean. In some cases it's not even clear if a particular combination of wedges actually was a distinct sign, or just a variant or miswritten form of another similar sign. The bottom line is that, while we know a lot about cuneiform writing nowadays, there's also a lot that we still _don't_ know, and may never know.

Comment: I think the underlying question has to be about logographic writing systems and bilingualism, where e.g. Sumerian characters can be read as Sumerian, or as Akkadian, and that is the source of multiple readings. If Akkadian has innovated characters, then I would wonder how the two readings for such characters came into existence.

Comment: Wiki sez of Akkadian "Many signs in the script were polyvalent, having both a syllabic and logographic meaning". The confusing part is the word "many": I don't know if the author means "some", "many" or "all".

Comment: @user6726: It means "many", arguably even "almost all". But it depends on how you count. Certainly, all the _commonly used_ signs _could_ be read in multiple ways; but on the other hand, most of them were _usually_ read in a single way, or at most in a few ways that could be reasonably easily distinguished from context. And of course the set of readings a particular sign could have depended not only on the language and dialect being written (and on local scribal traditions), but also on the genre and style of writing.

Comment: ... The sign AN mentioned by Draconis in their answer is notable for being one of the few signs with multiple _entirely distinct_ readings (i.e. not just close phonetic variations) that occur _commonly_ in pretty much all kinds of texts, even the simplest ones. And most of the time, it's pretty easy to tell whether it means /an/ or "a god's name follows" (those being the two most common uses in Akkadian), especially if you're familiar with basic Akkadian vocabulary and/or the names of the most commonly mentioned deities.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for your additions! Definitely, the meaning of most signs are pretty clear—especially to a literate native speaker, I'd imagine, but that's a hard hypothesis to test. The reason I think it answers this question well is because those clear meanings are context dependent. As you say, you know it's a determiner rather than `/an/` if what follows is the name of a god, for example.

Comment: +1, Akkadian also came to my mind. You may also want to include signs like ah/eh/ih/uh or qá/ga or ib/ip which can express a range of similar sounds and are disambiguated by nearby signs (e.g. id/it - ti = itti) or larger context (e.g. qá/ga - tu - um = qātum).

Answer (score 6):

It is the case in French. Such a differentiation is due to two distinct phenomena: assimilation & polyphonic letters.

An example of assimilations in French:

shop is transcribed in French "magasin" and is pronounced [maɡazɛ̃], but the word "oursin" is pronounced [uʁsɛ̃]. So the letter s can be pronounced [s] or [z].

An example of polyphonic letters in French:

The word "garage", meaning garage, is pronounced [gaʀaʒ]. This example shows that the letter g corresponds to two sounds [g] and [ʒ].

That can be generalised to other languages with old written traditions as English, Spanish and so on.

Let us add, ideograms (such the Kanji) are not an alphabetic writing system. Then, there is not relation between the characters and the signifier, instead the symbols are tied to the signified.

Comment: While absolutely correct, does this apply to *every* character in French? For example, is *q* ever anything other than `/k/`?

Comment: In French, /k/ is transcribed by the bigraph "qu" and rarely only by the character "q". This bigraph has also other pronounciations as [kw]. Every character, I don't know, I don't have such an information. But, I would say, from my experience, that most of the letters have several pronounciations.

Comment: In *garage* it's not just the *g* that carries the /ʒ/ sound, but at least the *ge*.

Comment: @vectory the word "girafe" is pronounced [ʒiʁaf]. Generally, the letter g corresponds to [ʒ], without being combined with e, and the the digrah gu carries the sound [g].

Comment: That's disingenuous. The e in garage is silent and its part of a digraph. I suppose there is not a single instance of a word ending on plain -g, because that tends to be -c. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @vectory the final -e it is not restricted to g. It is a orthographic rule in French where even masculine nouns have to end with the letter e. Otherwise, if I follow your affirmation I should consider the -e in "courge" as a part of the digraph ge and not the feminine marker. It is true that when the sequence "ge" is written , generally, you have to pronounce ʒ, but e is also pronounced. The word gelée is pronounced ʒəle and not ʒle. Yet, there are some exceptions when suffixs are added as mangea [mɑ̃ʒa] or mangeable [mɑ̃ʒabl]. It isn't always true that the digraph ge symbolises only ʒ.

Comment: @vectory: There are a few French words ending in silent -g : 'sang', 'rang', 'coing'. There are other words ending in -g, mostly inherited from English : 'gag', 'briefing', ...

Answer (score 6):

You're asking about a writing system, which is artificial. Even though language is learnt, it is considered natural. Language has meanings, and spoken language uses sounds to communicate those meanings. Written language converts the meanings to marks. One writing system may be used for multiple languages ([Latin variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script), [Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script), [Devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari), etc.), and one language may have multiple writing systems ([Sindhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindhi_language) is written in [Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script), Devanagari, and [Gujarati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_alphabet), as well as other historical scripts).

Your question is not so much about language, but a combination of language and writing. Language does not naturally have characters, but writing systems do. English is probably a good candidate language for its writing system. All "characters" and digraphs have at least two different pronunciations, although some may be viewed as being foreign, and not (yet) naturalised. As time goes on, this number could increase. English has been written for a long time and has had no spelling reforms, only standardisation. If we reformed English spelling, only people familiar with the old spelling would be able to read current English unchanged.

- a - various: /æ/ cat, /ɑ/ father, /ə/ apply
- b - /b/: bee, baby; silent: lamb, plumber, climb
- c - /k/: cat, coffee; /s/: city, cyan; (both in one word: success); silent: muscle; /ʃ/: liquorice
- ch - /t͡ʃ/: child; /ʃ/: cache; /x/: loch; /k/: school
- d - /d/: dog; /t/: jumped; /ɾ/: paddle
- e - various
- f - /f/: fish; /v/: of
- g - /ɡ/: gate; /d͡ʒ/: age; silent: gnome
- gh - /ɡ/: ghost; /f/: rough; silent: through
- h - /h/: hat; silent: hour
- i - various
- j - /d͡ʒ/: jet; /i/: fjord; /j/: Jugoslavia; /h/: Julio; /xw/: Juan
- k - /k/: kite; silent: knight
- l - /l/: lamp; /ɫ/ felt; silent: palm, walk; /j/: guillotine
- m - /m/: man; silent: mnemonic
- n - /n/: nose; silent: autumn
- o - various
- p - /p/: pet; silent: psalm
- ph - /f/: phone; /p/: diphthong, Phuket
- qu - /kw/: queen; /k/: plaque
- q - /k/: burqa; /t͡ʃ/: qi
- r - /ɹ/: red; silent: nurse
- s - /s/: stop; /z/: dogs; /ʃ/: sure; /ʒ/: unusual
- sh - /ʃ/: shop; /s.h/: mishap
- t - /t/: tap; /ɾ/: butter; /ʃ/: motion
- th - /θ/: thing; /ð/: this; /t/: Thames, Thailand
- u - various
- v - /v/: vain; /f/: Tchaikovsky
- w - /w/: wet; silent: write, sword, two
- wh - /w/: what; /h/: who
- x - /ks/: excel; /gz/: exit; silent: faux
- y - /j/: yellow; /i/: city
- z - /z/: zoo; silent: rendezvous

Some of these sound differences could be described as nuances, some seem quite different. It depends how different "different" is. Most letters have a primary sound, and a lifetime of exposure means an English speaker can correctly guess the pronunciation of unfamiliar words with a plethora of rules that are applied subconsciously.

For example, "b" is usually silent after "m". "c" is usually pronounced /s/ before the vowels "e", "i", and "y". "d" and "t" may be pronounced as [/ɾ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_and_alveolar_flaps) in quick speech (as opposed to careful speech), but is that different enough, or do you consider that sound to be an [allophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone) of /d/ and /t/? As an example, Sinhala has a letter "ව" that supposedly represents the sound /ʋ/. However, native speakers pronounce it as either [v] or [w] depending on the word, and consider both sounds to be the same, even though they can be different in other languages, such as English.

A writing system where *every* word had to be learnt independently, would take a long time to learn. There would need to be a lot of pressure from some source to prevent it from simplifying or being replaced. It is said that Vietnamese writing is now a lot easier to learn now that [the writing system is based on Latin letters instead of Chinese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_writing_in_Vietnam).

Since you've said in a comment that your motivation for asking is wanting to write a story, perhaps you should check out [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think it was a great idea to include silent letters. But why did you put [ɫ] in slashes. Why would it be a phoneme?

Comment: Careful, I don't think that there is any way you could argue that [ɾ] isn't an allophone of /d : t/. As you said that /t : d/ may be pronounced as [ɾ]. That is pretty much the definition of an allophone – and the similarity in pronunciation can easily be proven because they are homorganous consonants and [ɾ] doesn't resemble other consonants as closely. I also don't agree about the /r/ in nurse being silent (do you mean in RP etc?). Some of the irregular pronunciations are not universal. Could you explain your reasoning? :)

Comment: "v - always /v/: vain" Well, it's a weak argument, but there may still be some loan words like *verboten* /ˌfə(ɹ)ˈboʊ.tən/ (varying in pronunciation).

Comment: @tobiornottobi Also *von*, *Tchaikovsky*.  But in the older English spellings, until recent centuries, *v* was used like *u* at the beginning of a word, so there were spellings like *vpon*.  So the answer could just be changed to *Early Modern English*.  There are also words like *rooves* and *roofs* where both pronunciations occur, and probably there are speakers who pronounce it one way and write it the other, or read it one way regardless of the spelling.

Comment: Also *V* can be pronounced *five* or *fifth* when it's a Roman numeral.

Comment: And a silent *v*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveson-Gower_family

Comment: The only example I could think of originally for "v" was "nuclear wessels".

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Isn't that more the v being pronounced as if it were a w? In fact, the name apparently comes from Leves or Levis as a variant spelling of Lewis, and the "ev" is pronounced just like the "ew" in Lewis and many other words.

Comment: @abarnert The point is that in English, spelling is not always a good predictor of pronunciation, regardless of whether the word is a foreign one that is not yet naturalised, or a native English word.

Comment: @CJDennis Well, sure. I'm just pointing out that the spelling-pronunciation correspondence can sometimes _still_ be confusing even after you look it up and try to think it through. :)

Comment: For a real silent "v", try Alverdiscott (which has a silent v-e-r-d-i), or dozens of other towns that drop entire syllables. Although the one that really threw me was a town in the west country (can't remember the name) with a -dgv- in the middle of it. I was told to "pronounce the v like a w", but I had no idea what -dgw- is supposed to sounds like either. (It's pronounced like -dz-, of course.)

Comment: @abarnert My answer is supposed to be representative, not encyclopaedic or complete.

Comment: Sure, and your answer doesn't even use the Leveson-Gower in the first place, which is why I addressed the comment to Adam Bittlingmayer, rather than you.

Comment: I did this exercise yesterday, and you have a much better example for V than I ever could get. The R in "nurse" is arguable in rhotic accents. There are also irregular words like Worcester, forecastle, and sarsaparilla with silent Rs.

Answer (score 2):

I bring you: **"The strange case of Mexican *'x'*"**.

Letter 'X' in Mexican Spanish has *four* different sounds, and it takes some time for a non-native speaker to learn the nuances... Mostly, it's a matter of knowing the right pronunciation for each word.

- X can sound as you expect, /ks/ in words like "excluir" (exclude) or "extraño" (strange).
- Things start to be interesting when you pronounce "Mexico" in Spanish: you need to say /Méjico/ (say /Méksico/ and you may as well wear a T-Shirt saying "I'm a foreigner"). Same goes for "Oaxaca" and "Mexicali".
- It starts to get weird when you say "Xochimilco" (a borough in Mexico City): the "X" here has the sound /s/.
- And finally, if you say "Xola" (a metro station and a neighborhood in Mexico City), the "X" must sound /sh/ (don't say /sola/, which is the female form of "alone").

Hope this is an example of what you're looking for.

---

*P.S.*

I am Mexican. I live in Mexico City. I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Isn't xochimilco also pronounced with /sh/? It's from Aztec right?

Comment: @Wilson it comes from Nahuatl, indeed. Its pronunciation is `[sotʃiˈmilko]` (/sochimilco/). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xochimilco).

Comment: @Barranka Wiktionary mentions both /s/ and /ʃ/ for Spanish. And while Wiktionary is not the most secure source, the audio on Wikipedia does not reflect the long vowels of the transcription for Nahuatl [ʃoːtʃiˈmiːlko]. It might rather be a Spanish recording placed incorrectly.